# Why am I getting a nil pointer error depending on where I call BindPFlag?

Tags: go, go-cobra, viper-go

I've just recently started working with Go, and I've run into some
behavior working with Cobra and Viper that I'm not sure I understand.

This is a slightly modified version of the sample code you get by
running `cobra init`. In `main.go` I have:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/larsks/example/cmd"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

func main() {
    rootCmd := cmd.NewCmdRoot()
    cobra.CheckErr(rootCmd.Execute())
}
```

In `cmd/root.go` I have:

```
package cmd

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

var cfgFile string

func NewCmdRoot() *cobra.Command {
    config := viper.New()

    var cmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "example",
        Short: "A brief description of your application",
        PersistentPreRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            initConfig(cmd, config)
        },
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Printf("This is a test\n")
        },
    }

    cmd.PersistentFlags().StringVar(&cfgFile, "config", "", "config file (default is $HOME/.example.yaml)")
    cmd.PersistentFlags().String("name", "", "a name")

  // *** If I move this to the top of initConfig
  // *** the code runs correctly.
    config.BindPFlag("name", cmd.Flags().Lookup("name"))

    return cmd
}

func initConfig(cmd *cobra.Command, config *viper.Viper) {
    if cfgFile != "" {
        // Use config file from the flag.
        config.SetConfigFile(cfgFile)
    } else {
        config.AddConfigPath(".")
        config.SetConfigName(".example")
    }

    config.AutomaticEnv() // read in environment variables that match

    // If a config file is found, read it in.
    if err := config.ReadInConfig(); err == nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Using config file:", config.ConfigFileUsed())
    }

  // *** This line triggers a nil pointer reference.
    fmt.Printf("name is %s\n", config.GetString("name"))
}
```

This code will panic with a nil pointer reference at the final call to
`fmt.Printf`:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x50 pc=0x6a90e5]
```

If I move the call to `config.BindPFlag` from the `NewCmdRoot`
function to the top of the `initConfig` command, everything runs
without a problem.

What's going on here? According to the Viper docs regarding the use of
`BindPFlags`:

> Like BindEnv, the value is not set when the binding method is
> called, but when it is accessed. This means you can bind as early as
> you want, even in an init() function.

That's almost exactly what I'm doing here. At the time I call
`config.BindPflag`, `config` is non-nil, `cmd` is non-nil, and the
`name` argument has been registered.

I assume there's something going on with my use of `config` in a
closure in `PersistentPreRun`, but I don't know exactly why that is
causing this failure.

Comment: `cfgFile` is set/read out of sequence. If a flag sets the config path, this input value will not be seen by `initConfig`.

Comment: @colm.anseo Can you expand on that a bit? I'm not clear on how `cfgFile` being unset would lead to the nil pointer error.

Comment: can you explain `cobra.CheckErr` a bit?

Comment: @nipuna that is described [in the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/cobra#CheckErr).

Comment: for me, above code is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any issue if I use `cmd.PersistentFlags().Lookup("name")`.

```
    // *** If I move this to the top of initConfig
    // *** the code runs correctly.
    pflag := cmd.PersistentFlags().Lookup("name")
    config.BindPFlag("name", pflag)
```

Considering you just registered [persistent flags](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/eb3b6397b1b5d1b0a2cd66a9afe0520f480c0a87/README.md#persistent-flags) (flag will be available to the command it's assigned to as well as every command under that command), it is safer to call `cmd.PersistentFlags().Lookup("name")`, rather than `cmd.Flags().Lookup("name")`.

The latter returns `nil`, since the `PersistentPreRun` is only called when `rootCmd.Execute()` is called, which is *after* `cmd.NewCmdRoot()`.
At `cmd.NewCmdRoot()` levels, flags have not yet been initialized, even after some were declared "persistent".

Comment: Good catch, and now I have some idea what particular value was `nil`.  The situation is still a bit confusing: if `cmd.Flags().Lookup("name")` is returning `nil`, I am surprised that `config.BindPFlag` isn't reporting an error.

Comment: I'm going to leave this marked as the accepted answer, since it pointed me in the right direction, but I've written up a more detailed answer that I hope will help if someone else runs into the same problem. Let me know if you think I missed anything or misrepresented anything.

Answer (score 3):

I thought this was interesting so I did some digging and [found your exact problem documented in an issue](https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/292#issuecomment-327996518). The problematic line is this:

```golang
config.BindPFlag("name", cmd.Flags().Lookup("name"))
//                           ^^^^^^^
```

You created a persistent flag, but bound the flag to the `Flags` property. If you change your code to bind to `PersistentFlags`, everything will work as intended even with this line in `NewCmdRoot`:

```golang
config.BindPFlag("name", cmd.PersistentFlags().Lookup("name"))
```

Comment: @VonC yeah I noticed you solved the issue already but this was meant to be a companion to your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This ends up being a little more complex than it might appear at first glance, so while the other answers here helped me resolve the problem I'd like to add a little detail.

There are some nuances in the documentation that aren't particularly clear if you're just starting to work with Cobra. Let's start with the documentation for the [`PersistentFlags`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/cobra#Command.PersistentFlags) method:

> PersistentFlags returns the persistent FlagSet specifically set in the current command.

The key is in *...in the current command*. In my `NewCmdRoot` root method, we can use `cmd.PersistentFlags()` because the root command is the *current command*. We can even use `cmd.PersistentFlags()` in the `PersistentPreRun` method, **as long as we're not processing a subcommand**.

If we were to re-write `cmd/root.go` from the example so that it includes a subcommand, like this...

```
package cmd

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

var cfgFile string

func NewCmdSubcommand() *cobra.Command {
    var cmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "subcommand",
        Short: "An example subcommand",
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Printf("This is an example subcommand\n")
        },
    }

    return cmd
}

func NewCmdRoot() *cobra.Command {
    config := viper.New()

    var cmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "example",
        Short: "A brief description of your application",
        PersistentPreRun: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            initConfig(cmd, config)
        },
        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            fmt.Printf("Hello, world\n")
        },
    }

    cmd.PersistentFlags().StringVar(
    &cfgFile, "config", "", "config file (default is $HOME/.example.yaml)")
    cmd.PersistentFlags().String("name", "", "a name")

    cmd.AddCommand(NewCmdSubcommand())

    err := config.BindPFlag("name", cmd.PersistentFlags().Lookup("name"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return cmd
}

func initConfig(cmd *cobra.Command, config *viper.Viper) {
    name, err := cmd.PersistentFlags().GetString("name")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("name = %s\n", name)

    if cfgFile != "" {
        // Use config file from the flag.
        config.SetConfigFile(cfgFile)
    } else {
        config.AddConfigPath(".")
        config.SetConfigName(".example")
    }

    config.AutomaticEnv() // read in environment variables that match

    // If a config file is found, read it in.
    if err := config.ReadInConfig(); err == nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Using config file:", config.ConfigFileUsed())
    }

    // *** This line triggers a nil pointer reference.
    fmt.Printf("name is %s\n", config.GetString("name"))
}
```

...we would find that it works when executing the root command:

```
$ ./example
name =
name is
Hello, world
```

But it *fails* when we run the subcommand:

```
[lars@madhatter go]$ ./example subcommand
panic: flag accessed but not defined: name

goroutine 1 [running]:
example/cmd.initConfig(0xc000172000, 0xc0001227e0)
        /home/lars/tmp/go/cmd/root.go:55 +0x368
example/cmd.NewCmdRoot.func1(0xc000172000, 0x96eca0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/lars/tmp/go/cmd/root.go:32 +0x34
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc000172000, 0x96eca0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000172000, 0x96eca0)
        /home/lars/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:836 +0x231
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc00011db80, 0x0, 0xffffffff, 0xc0000240b8)
        /home/lars/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:960 +0x375
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /home/lars/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:897
main.main()
        /home/lars/tmp/go/main.go:11 +0x2a
```

This is because the subcommand inherits the `PersistentPreRun` command from the root (this is what the `Persistent` part means), but when this method runs, the `cmd` argument passwd to `PersistentPreRun` is no longer the root command; it's the `subcommand` command. When we try to call `cmd.PersistentFlags()`, it fails because *the current command* doesn't have any persistent flags associated with it.

In this case, we need to instead use the [`Flags`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/spf13/cobra#Command.Flags) method:

> Flags returns the complete FlagSet that applies to this command (local and persistent declared here and by all parents).

This gives us access to persistent flags declared by parents.

An additional issue, that doesn't appear to be called out explicitly in the documentation, is that `Flags()` is only available after command processing has been run (that is, after you call `cmd.Execute()` on the command or a parent). That means we can use it in `PersistentPreRun`, but we *can't* use it in `NewCmdRoot` (because that method finishes before we process the command line).

---

TL;DR

- We have to use `cmd.PersistentFlags()` in `NewCmdRoot` because we're looking for persistent flags applied to the *current command*, and the value from `Flags()` won't be available yet.
- We need to use `cmd.Flags()` in `PersistentPreRun` (and other persistent commands methods) because when processing a subcommand, `PersistentFlags` will only look for persistent flags on the *current command*, but won't traverse parents. We need to use `cmd.Flags()` instead, which will roll up persistent flags declared by parents.